# Java - Storing the output of a for loop into an array

Tags: java

I'm using a for loop to create the first 400 multiples of 13, and I'm trying to to store these numbers into an array. The specific issue is on 5th line. I understand that this code is making the programme write to the first element of the array, which is causing the issue. Is there any way I can store the numbers sequentially?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] thirteenMultiples = new int[400];
    for (int dex = 1; dex < thirteenMultiples.length; dex ++) {
        int multiples = 13 * dex; 
        thirteenMultiples[0] = multiples;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(thirteenMultiples));
```

Comment: Use `dex`, since it's incremented each loop: `thirteenMultiples[dex] = multiples`.

Comment: Voted to close, simple typo/syntax problem.

Comment: This deserves an upvote? I rather start believing!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Array indices start at 0, so change `int dex = 1` to `int dex = 0`. Also, you should use your counting variable `dex` to write to the right array index:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] thirteenMultiples = new int[400];
    for (int dex = 0; dex < thirteenMultiples.length; dex ++) {
        int multiples = 13 * dex; 
        thirteenMultiples[dex] = multiples;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(thirteenMultiples));
    }
}
```

BTW: `Arrays.toString(thirteenMultiples)` is quite an expensive operation to do on every iteration (try to code this method yourself and you'll see what i mean). Maybe you should just print the current value of `thirteenMultiples[dex]` and print you array once the loop has finished. I assume you're just testing and trying stuff for now, but i think it's good to keep such things in mind from the beginning ;)

Answer (score 4):

thirteenMultiples[dex] in place of thirteenMultiple[0], because dex is equal to the index each time for loop runs. For ex - for dex =1 you store multiple at [1], then it increases to 2 then it becomes [2] and you store the next multiple at 2. Hence it stores each new value at new index.

Also start dex from 0 as array starts from 0 index.

Answer (score 0):

I guess in this case, it is better to use a List rather than an array. Your code will look cleaner

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> thirteenMultiples = new ArrayList<Integer>;
    for (int dex = 0; dex < 400; dex ++) {
        thirteenMultiples.add(13 * dex)
    }
    System.out.println(thirteenMultiples);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternate perspective. I'll look into this.